# Gaussian Copula Approximation of an intractable distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, approximation

I am currently encountering this problem:

I have an intractable distribution and I want to minimize the KL divergence of this distribution and a Gaussian Copula(or 0 mean gaussian distribution). So we just need to find out the precision matrix.

The distribution is so complicated that it is not really possible to calculate the gradient or Hessian of the distribution function. All we can to is to evaluate the distribution function.

Is there any algorithm that actually solves such a problem or any suggestions on this? Thank you very much!